# Retry the method with same parameter that caused it to panic

Tags: go

[Code Play Golang Link](https://play.golang.org/p/zjMPNRxH7i)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func test(i int){
    defer func(){
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Inside Recover: ", r)
        }

    }()
    for try := 1 ; try <= i ; try++{
        if (i == 3){
            panic("Panic")
        }
        fmt.Printf("i: %d try: %d\n", i , try)
    }
}

func main(){

    for i := 1 ; i < 5 ; i++{
        test(i)
    }
}
```

The method panics and skips to next `i` value without trying `i` times. Is there a way in which we can recover from the panic and retry for the same value of `i` that caused panic ?

Comment: you can pass `i` to `panic`, this is what is returned by `recover`. however most likely you should be using error values instead. panics in go are used predominantely for unexpected errors that are unrecoverable.

Comment: @kostya: I completely agree with you on using error values. My problem is that some functions are incomplete so panic is being used. We just want to make sure that the server doesn't crash and is available to process next requests.

Comment: Are you sure you have to use panic? From your code seems returning a second error parameter - the godiomatic way - is more suited for this case. FYI panic/recover is not what we call try/catch in other languages. Errors are for error handling in Go. panics are used when the program should panic like when it has not access to database or file-system (so continue to work is pointless) or some other external (C) lib does not work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you wanted to test any function that could fail with this construct, best without having to change that function. Here my solution. Hope this is what you were looking for.

[Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/tetjWOEpDS)

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func test(i int) error {
    if i == 3 {
        return errors.New("Panic")
    }
    return nil
}

func retryWrapper(i, try int) {
    err := test(i)
    fmt.Printf("i: %d try: %d\n", i, try)

    if err != nil && try < 5 {
        retryWrapper(i, try+1)
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 1; i < 5; i++ {
        retryWrapper(i, 1)
    }
}
```

This works with functions that return an error. If your function panics, you will need to change the test function with a defer/recover like this:

[Recover Sample](https://play.golang.org/p/Wusm-O7FLT)

```
func test(i int) (err error) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            err = errors.New(r.(string))
        }
    }()
    if i == 3 {
        panic("Panic")
    }
    return
}
```

Note: retry is limited to 5 trys to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: So are you suggesting that in defer recover block I should manually create an error and return it?

Comment: correct. And based on that call the function again from the outside. If you try to call the function again in the defer block, you have to change the function with additional parameters to know when to stop retrying for example.